# Disabling the effect of _GLIBCXX_DEBUG for a specific variable

Tags: c++

If a C++ program is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, is there a way to specify in its source code that for a specific variable of type `std::vector` I DO NOT want the "debug" version of this class but the "normal" version instead?

My use-case is the following:

I have a C library (which I will call `libA`) and a C++ library (which I will call `libB`) presenting a C interface. Those libraries haven't been compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`. The main program (which is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`) must call a function of `libA` and pass it an `std::vector<char>*` converted into a `void*`. `libA` calls a `libB` function that is given the `void*` and casts it back into an `std::vector<char>*` to use it (oh the joy of passing C++ data through a C layer...). Since the main program is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` but `libB` isn't, the `std::vector<char>` class in the main program and in `libB` actually have a different implementation, which leads to errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably most robust to create a `void* createNDebugVec(char const* begin, char const* end);` function, and put that in its own .cpp file. In that .cpp file, explicitly `#undef GLIBCXX_DEBUG` before including anything. This allows you to create a non-debug `std::vector` and return it pre-cast to `void*`. You'll probably need a matching `void destroyNDebugVec(void*);`.

Note that `void* createNDebugVec(std::vector<char> const& src);` won't work, for essentiall the same reason.

Comment: Is this definitely safe? Intuitively I'd expect this to be a sort of "UB" from the runtime's perspective, mixing flags like that. Mind you, I guess it has to support this in order to avoid insane constraints on what things you can link together. Though if that were the case then the OP wouldn't have a problem in the first place. Meh

Comment: It's indeed technically UB, and a reasonable implementation might have some `std::vector` methods precompiled in its CRT. You can see how that might break. But it's pretty much UB from the start, given that you have two vector definitions in the program at large.

Answer (score 1):

you can `#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG` before using the `#include<vector>` in your main program.

Just to be sure I would declare a non template class inheriting `std::vector<char>` in which you use the `#undef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG` trick and use the instance of this class to pass data to libB.